# Keyboard Listener in MvvmCross

Tags: wpf, .net-core, mvvmcross

I just started using mvvmCross and wondering how I can capture a specific keyboard key which I can push wherever I am on the app.

I would put the listener in my ViewModel class ( public class TestViewModel : MvxViewModel)

Usually you do it with something like that;

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F5)
    {
        //refresh
    }
}
```

but KeyEventArgs is quite unknown in this framework. I also could not find any information on their website.

Thanks

Stephan

---

As suggested I added following code to my MainWindow WPF:

```
    this.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Key pushed: " + e.Key);
        if (e.Key == Key.F5)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("F5 was pressed in View");
        }
    };
```

In my controller I added following:

```
public IMvxCommand UpdateInformationCommand { get; set; }
UpdateInformationCommand = new MvxCommand(AddGuest); //in the constructor
```

When I push F5 I get the correct console output, but I am not sure how to trigger the UpdateInformationCommand  command. In the WPF it seems quite easy by just adding the command to a button, but I don't know how to do it programmatically

---

Update:
I added:

```
<views:MvxWpfView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding UpdateInformationCommand}" />
</views:MvxWpfView.InputBindings>
```

into my view but now the issue is that the focus in on the MainWindow.xaml which I can change by clicking on a control inside my SomeView, but I am stucked in how to change the focus by code. I also tried:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be implemented platform specific. So in the case of WPF you should be able to do something like:

```
public new SomeViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (SomeViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
}

// constructor
public SomeView()
{
    this.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case VirtualKey.Number0:
                ViewModel.UpdateInformationCommand.Execute();
                break;
            case VirtualKey.Number1:
                ViewModel.UpdateInformationCommand.Execute();
                break;
                
            // etc
        }
    };
}
```

And if you want every view to have this you can make it a base view.

Comment: The issue is my binding between the View and the ViewModel. When I create a new instance I can use it, but I does not affect my current view. I followed the https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/TipCalc/ example and modified the MainWindow.xaml.cs class with the keyboard trigger, but to run the command I also must do some binding.I tried this eg. var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainWindow, InformationViewModel>() but this wont allow calling the command.

Comment: It seems I can easily use InPutBindngs in the XAML itself:  
   <views:MvxWpfView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding UpdateInformationCommand}" />
    </views:MvxWpfView.InputBindings>
but then I will have to focus issue which mean in the code it would be easier, in special because it is not the MainWindow but the MainWindow from the Views folder

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the issue with a Messenger.
Firstly, I created for the MainWindow a ViewModel that receives the command from the MainWindow.xaml
to connect the viewmodel with the view I added the code

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

to the MainWindowView.xaml.cs

Secondly I use the Messenger which creates a service and publishes this:

```
_messenger.Publish(message);
```

Lastly, in my InformationViewModel I subscribed to the event:

```
_token = messenger.Subscribe<KeyboardMessage>(OnLocationMessage);
```

If this is the best way, I don’t know.